# Preventing jQuery mobile from setting document.title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

It looks like jQuery mobile sets `document.title` to the text content of `data-role="header"`, example:

```
<div data-position="fixed" data-role="header">
    <h1>This text</h1>
</div>
```

I have a hack workaround to prevent this as such:

`$('div[data-role="page"]').bind('pageshow',function(){document.title = "My title"});`

Is there a better/more semantic way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Another solution would be to copy the original document title to the data-title attribute of each page:

```
$(":jqmData(role='page')").attr("data-title", document.title);
```

The advantage of this approach over changing the title on pageshow is that it will prevent document title flicker during page transitions.

Answer (score 5):

If you wrap your  value around div it will not update the title. Like this:

```
<div data-position="fixed" data-role="header">
    <div><h1>This text</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great; to maintain the styling and accessibility, be sure to add `<h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">`.

Comment: Your solution makes it look right @LukeDennis - however, then the original problem comes back. So this solution does not preserve the original look.

Answer (score 2):

I would just patch jQuery mobile to remove the unwanted behaviour. It appears to be in `jquery.mobile.navigation.js`. You could rebuild jQuery Mobile to get the minified version again.

If you were feeling ambitious, you could even submit a bug to jQuery Mobile asking that this be an option (and possibly even write a patch yourself, if you're comfortable doing so).

Comment: Posted the issue to the forums. This may only be a temporary sort of thing until I get a native app working, so I'm not immediately inclined to jump into library modification just yet. Good suggestion, though.

Answer (score 1):

The jqmData option here didn't work for me. The H1 wrapping option messed up the looks which I would need to correct through CSS. What did work for me and is actually documented by jQuery Mobile is:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.2/docs/pages/page-titles.html

Which comes down to adding the data-title attribute to the div with data-role="page":

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-title="MyPage - @ViewBag.Title">
```

In this particular example I'm setting the page title to "MyPage - " followed by the page title as set through MVC in the ViewBag.

Answer (score 0):

> $(":jqmData(role='page')").attr("data-title", document.title);

This works as proposed by @stanislaw-osinski - however, I had to use it like this to get it work in jQuery Mobile v1.4.5:

```
<script>
$(document).bind("pageinit", function(){
     // Patch to prevent overwriting <title></title>
    $(":jqmData(role='page')").attr("data-title", document.title);
});
</script>
```